# Validity of the following Entity Relationship Model?

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

Before I go ahead and convert my entity relationship diagram into SQL statements, I thought I'd ask if someone could verify if this model doesn't contain any absurdities and anomalies that will appear once I have a SQL database schema.

I am particularly unsure about my cardinality of a relationship between Customer and VIP. Also, Supplier and CD relationship. **start_date** of the VIP entity - should it be a weak key? Are there any other potential weak keys besides the *name* attribute of the **Song** entity?

[image: E/R Model]

## Legend

- Entity [image]
- Attribute [image]
- Weak Entity [image]
- Relationship [image]
- Identifying Relationship [image]
- Cardinality Ratio [image]

I've used the following websites as references to construct my diagram:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ERD_Representation.svg
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model
3. http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cse670/cse670Ch2.xht

Software used to create the diagram: [Dia (Linux)](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/)

Comment: Randomly - could two CD's contain the same song? Like a "hits" compliation or some such? Would that be another song record? or would you maybe need to break out the relationship with another table (cd's, songs, songstoCD { songid, cdid, track# }) or some such?

Comment: my UML is weak - so if this diagram already says that, nevermind my comment!

Comment: @Prescott Each CD can contain only one unique song name. Fairly simplistic model.

Comment: Ah ok - so no need to know that maybe an artist has song X on two cd's? you'd just have two records that say song X - Cd1, song X - cd2 and assume that song X is the same song X? or you don't care about that particular relationship at all? I think you get it though, just curious

Comment: The "is" relationship between Customer and VIP is an instance of the "gen-spec" pattern.  There are better ways of modeling gen-spec in ER diagrams.  When you go to convert to SQL, you'll want to know how to design SQL tables that model gen-spec.

Comment: I would consider "name" in the producer entity a weak key. Even music producers can have "common" (duplicating) names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is a late answer, but in case it's useful there are two improvements you can make.

1) The "is-a" relationship between "VIP" and "CUSTOMER" indicates the presence of a superclass (customer) and subclass (vip). You may want to model VIP as a subclass.

2) Since you are tracking dates for the relationship "rents", the cardinality must be taken "over time". Therefore the cardinality on both sides is "N" (i.e., not "1" on the side of customers)

Minor improvement: in "Song" (weak entity class) set the partial identifier as "track" rather than "name"; this will allow for multiple recordings of the same song on a CD (e.g., 2 versions). The track number will always be unique within the CD